# How do I submit an html form inside an iframe without changing the outer page?

Tags: javascript, http, iframe

I'm editing some existing html where the javascript loads a another page inside an iframe. In the page is an html form. When I hit submit, I'd like for the outer page to stay and the iframe to change to the results page. However, right now the whole page changes to the results page for the form. I'm guessing there's a way to solve this javascript. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Target the form to the iframe:

```
<iframe name="foo"></iframe>

<form target="foo"></form>
```

Comment: How do you get the right URL the form is posting to to load in the iframe? Presumably that's `action="[URL]"` but that's causing the POST to be a GET instead for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `target` attribute of the form tag. You can specify the frame.