# PHP $_POST and iframes

Tags: php, forms, post, iframe

first: is it POSSIBLE to make a form's action an iframe in the page? and second: if it's possible, how would I go about this?

`<form target="framename">`

`<input type="text" name="text" /><br>`
`<input type="submit" />`

`</form>`

`<iframe name="framename" src="http://examplesite.com/framename.php"></iframe>`

Comment: Make sure you don't have `action="something"` inside of form tag.

Comment: would it also be screwy if i had a method??

Comment: This is wrong, you need action="http://examplesite.com/framename.php" on your form tag. See my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, use the target attribute for the FORM element to reference a named iframe like here: [How do I submit an html form inside an iframe without changing the outer page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841886/how-do-i-submit-an-html-form-inside-an-iframe-without-changing-the-outer-page)

```
<form target="myframe" action="someaction.php">
...
</form>
<iframe name="myframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: when i do that, the iframe changes immediately to the contents of the page from which i am submitting it

Comment: though (and you did not say this) it worked only when i had a target as the frame name and the action as the iframe src

Comment: This is still wrong, it doesn't answer the question. Mark my answer as the correct answer, the use of "action" is essential

Answer (score 2):

add `target="my_frame"` to the form tag

```
<form target="my_frame" action="http://examplesite.com/framename.php">
```

and then add `name="my_frame"` to the iframe

```
<iframe name="my_frame">
```

Comment: What's your action="" tag say on the form? if you don't have one, then that's what it would do.